# FontStyleProperty' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I want to code my own `RichTextBox` in vb.net "wpf window"?

I got some already created `RTB` but they are in "Form" but I want in "wpf window"? Or please some one guide me which option is best to create my system base application WPF window or page or "vbForm"?

I try this code in "wpf window" but got error when I imports these two libraries

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

Private Sub bbb_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles bbb.Click
    Dim vvv As Double
    Dim ff As New FontDialog
    ff.ShowDialog()
    Dim dd As String = ff.Font.Name
    Dim ddd As TextSelection = rrr.Selection
    ddd.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontStyleProperty, dd)

End Sub
```

in this code if I does not `Imports System.Windows.Forms` then `Dim ff As New FontDialog` not working if I Imports `System.Windows.Forms` then above mentioned error occurred:

> FontStyleProperty is not a member of
>   'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

Comment: You certainly want to use `Imports System.Windows.Controls`, which gets you the namespace of the WPF RichTextBox, not the one from WinForms.

Comment: The Exception is thrown as there is no 'FontStyle' Property for System.Windows.Forms.'RichTextBox' and if you importSystem.Windows.Controls FontDialog does not exist.  Use SelectionFont instead of FontStyle Property

Comment: same issue only one thing work fontdialog or richtext box dame shit